# Java Script mvc C#

Tags: java

I have done this code for downloading data in **mvc**.But when I download pdf file then some data is missing.What should I do for this.
Can any one help me please.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var t = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
   "pageLength": 1000,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]});
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Your tagging makes no sense - what does this have to do with Java? JavaScript and Java are unrelated.

Comment: @Shaour Faxal.. seems like you are looking for missing code you downloaded online. This is wrong..think how we are going to fill up missing code. Since you are new here you need to learn more about how StackOverflow works..

Answer (score 0):

You Select DatatableTools Or Datatable file Export Jquery Plugin Download.
Use To Sample Code

Referece Link

http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html